# How do I bring individual windows of an application to the front?

Tags: window-manager

When I have multiple browser or VSCode windows I sometimes want to look at things side by side. But when I bring VSCode to the front with Cmd+Tab they all come to the front and often hide the thing I wanted to look at.

How do I only show some windows?

Answer (score 3):

This works only for one window at a time: after navigating to desired app using <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⇥</kbd> keep holding command key and press <kbd>↓</kbd> (down-arrow). This will bring up App Exposé i.e preview of all windows of current app. You can navigate to desired window using arrow keys and bring it forward by pressing <kbd>⏎</kbd> (enter).

If you have lot of windows or they have similar visual layout you can use quick view by pressing spacebar to make certain that you bring forward correct window.